# VBA: How to Convert Text to Columns with Semicolon

Tags: excel, vba

How to Convert Text to Columns with Semicolon.

My excel has ";;", I need to show one empty cell when I Convert Text to Columns.

Example:

[image]

After run VBA and I need to show like this below:

[image]

Comment: Try using the macro recorder and text-to-columns. Works 100% fine for me.

Comment: Uncheck "treat consecutive delimiters as one"

Answer (score 0):

Please See Thee Bellow Mention Code

Sub SplitName()

Dim txt As String

Dim i As Integer

Dim fullname As Variant

txt = ActiveCell.Value

fullname = Split(txt, ";;")

For i = o To UBound(fullname)

Cells(1, i + 1).Value = fullname(i)

Next i[image]

End Sub